# Upload a .pdf file to a Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

Within an Access 2007 application, I'm creating a static report in .pdf format. I want to create it, then export the static report (not the data itself) to a Sharepoint Document Library. The intent is for it to be a public repository, no versioning. Each report will carry a unique name.

I'm a seasoned vba programmer, but using Sharepoint services is new to me. How do I go about doing this? Assume I can identify the file name and location after I've generated it, and I know the Sharepoint library URL, and have permissions. Where do I go from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft did some magic in SharePoint to make the libraries appear as Windows network shares to the clients. So, your program can just save the file to the UNC path.

So if you are logged on as a user with permissions to the library and the URL to the library is `http://SHAREPOINT/Department/Files/` (for example), you can just save or copy the PDF files to `\\SHAREPOINT\Department\Files\`.